# Logically Impossible to fetch this particular string.?

Tags: sql, string, shell, awk, logic

I have 3 strings which are random and look somewhat like this

```
1) ENTL.COMPENSATION REM      REVERSE PAYMENT COUPON ON ISIN //IT0004889033  IN A TRIPARTY //TRANSACTION WITH 95724
2) 01P ISIN DE000A1H36U5 QTY 44527000, //C/P 19696
3) COUPON ISIN XS0820547742 QTY 466750,
```

Now what is expected is to fetch the values *IT0004889033* or *DE000A1H36U5* or *XS0820547742*. If you observe the 3 strings, these 3 expected values come rite after the ISIN. So we can take isin as a reference and then fetch the values after ISIN. But that is not what is required it seems. We should not fetch the value by taking some value as a reference.

Since the expected value is *IT0004889033* which is a 12 digit character the information I have is; first 2 characters are alphabets, next 9 are alphanumeric and the last one is a digit. Just with this information is it possible to do a wildcard search or something and fetch this 12 digit value.?

I'm totally lost on this one logically.

Comment: Are you using a database for this?  If not, please remove the sql tag.  If yes, then please add the database to the tags.

Comment: basically we are using a thrid party scripting language. So if nothing works out i thought of calling sql from the script as my last resort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mentioned that *ISIN* **should not** be used as a reference.  Therefore, the only thing for sure is that the string to be found starts with 2 letters, followed by 9 letters and/or numbers, and ends with a number.

I saved your example text as *tmp*, and ran the following *egrep* command... seems to work for me:

```
jim@debian:~/tmp$ egrep -o "[a-zA-Z]{2}[a-zA-Z0-9]{9}[0-9]{1}" tmp
IT0004889033
DE000A1H36U5
XS0820547742
```

The above solution is more *correct* than the previous ones because it takes a fixed amount of characters to filter the results.  Only 12-character strings will be returned by the above code.

I hope this helps!

Comment: thanks a lot actually yeah i wanted a way to fetch these values without using the ISIN as the reference. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Using `grep -oP`:

```
grep -oP 'ISIN\W+\K\w+' file
IT0004889033
DE000A1H36U5
XS0820547742
```

if `grep -P` isn't available then you can use use awk:

```
awk -F '.*ISIN[^0-9a-zA-Z]*| ' '{print $2}' file
IT0004889033
DE000A1H36U5
XS0820547742
```

OR else:

```
awk -F '.*ISIN[^[:alnum:]]*| ' '{print $2}' file
```

Comment: Wow the first `awk` has by far the biggest `FS` I've ever seen! `:)`

Comment: If it worked out for you then mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.

Comment: can you please explain the second awk solution

Comment: Yes sure. awk uses `'.*ISIN[^[:alnum:]]*| ` regex, which means input from line start to `ISIN` followed by one or more non-word characters OR else a just space.