# Parse a two values from the file

Tags: bash, sed, text-parsing, string-parsing

Part of my file looks like so:

```
STATUS REPORT FOR JOB: Job_logging
Generated: 2014-03-14 07:05:03
   Job start time=2014-03-13 06:37:49
   Job end time=2014-03-13 06:37:51
   Job elapsed time=00:00:02
   Job status=1 (Finished OK)
      Stage: Oracle_Connector_0, 1 rows input
      Stage start time=2014-03-13 06:37:51, end time=2014-03-13 06:37:51, elapsed=00:00:00
         Link: DSLink2, 1 rows
      Stage: Peek_3, 1 rows input
      Stage start time=2014-03-13 06:37:51, end time=2014-03-13 06:37:51, elapsed=00:00:00

     Status code = 0
     Link: DSLink2, 1 rows
```

I need to extract values that stand for Job start time and Job end time

So i need **2014-03-13 06:37:49** and **2014-03-13 06:37:51** to be saved into two separate variables: v1 and v2.

How do I do that using BASH?

I've already killed about an hour playing with strings concatanation and sed but still got nothing.

Little help, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `grep` for this:

```
$ grep -Po '(?<=Job start time=).*' file
2014-03-13 06:37:49

$ grep -Po '(?<=Job end time=).*' file
2014-03-13 06:37:51
```

It used a look-behind that checks what comes after `Job start/end time=` in the given file.

And to store into a variable, use

```
$ var=$(grep -Po '(?<=Job end time=).*' file)
$ echo "$var"
2014-03-13 06:37:51
```

Comment: You made my mid-day :) Thanks fedorqui!

Answer (score 2):

Using awk it can be found in single line:

```
awk -F 'Job (start|end) time=' 'NF>1{print $2}' file
2014-03-13 06:37:49
2014-03-13 06:37:51
```

To read both values in variables:

```
IFS=';' && read v1 v2 < <(awk -F 'Job (start|end) time=' 'NF>1{printf "%s;", $2}' file)
```

Comment: +1 for making me witness the second biggest `FS` I've ever seen. First one is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22188342/970195). Just shy of 1 char. `:P`

Answer (score 0):

This is simple and easy to read:

```
grep "Job start time" test.txt | cut -d"=" -f2
grep "Job end time" test.txt | cut -d"=" -f2
```

This searches for the lines containing your specific string, sets the delimeter as = between the two, and takes the field on the right of it.

Answer (score 0):

With `sed`:

```
v1=$(sed -rn 's/.*Job start time=(.*)/\1/p' yourfile)
v2=$(sed -rn 's/.*Job end time=(.*)/\1/p' yourfile)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
eval `sed -n 's/^ *Job start time=\(.*\)/v1="\1"/p
s/^ *Job end time=\(.*\)/v2="\1"/p' YourFile`
```

tested on aix/bash (so no GNU sed)